# Can I ask questions about the talmud and Chumash?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask questions about the Talmud and Chumash?

Comment: @msh210 How did we miss this until now?

Comment: @DoubleAA, in what sense? It was on the main site, not this one. It was closed but not migrated.

Comment: related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/148/would-this-be-an-appropriate-site-for-people-to-ask-technical-gemara-questions?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

Yes, no problem; we have a good number of such questions, in fact.